# Isabelle: Opposite of "intro impI"

Tags: isabelle, apply-script

If my goal state is `foo ==> bar --> qux`, I know that I can use the statement

```
apply (intro impI)
```

to yield the goal state `foo ==> bar ==> qux`. What about the other direction? Which command will send me back to the goal state `foo ==> bar --> qux`?

---

The best I have come up with so far is

```
apply (rule_tac P="bar" in rev_mp, assumption, thin_tac "bar")
```

but that's rather clunky, and I'd like to learn if there's a nicer way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
apply (rule_tac P="bar" in rev_mp, assumption, thin_tac "bar")
```

you can write

```
apply (erule_tac P="bar" in rev_mp)
```

where `erule_tac` eliminates the matched assumption for you so you don't need the `thin_tac` anymore.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks Brian. That's just what I was after. Final question: do you have any tips for dealing with the case where `bar` is a very long formula? Can I, for instance, just tell `erule_tac` to work on assumption number 2?

Comment: I should mention that `apply (erule rev_mp) back` works, but `back` is a bit ugly...

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you want to stay in *apply-style*. Then this is just a puzzle with probably many possible solutions. Here is one:

```
apply (unfold atomize_imp, rule)
```

or a bit more explicit

```
apply (unfold atomize_imp, rule impI)
```

where the `unfold atomize_imp` replaces *all* occurrences of `==>` by `-->`. Then, in general, you can specify the number of `-->` that should be replaced by `==>` (starting from the left), by a corresponding number of `rule` (or `rule impI`).

Anyway, if you would use *Isar-style* than you just state what you want to have explicitly and almost any automatic tool will be able to fill in the rest.